# Report with four tables for each account

Tags: report, birt

I am struggling in the creation of a report including four tables.

Those tables should be the same for each account. I use just one dataset. When I run the report, the data is good, but tables listing appears wrong.

First all `BALANCE DETAIL` tables for all accounts selected are listed, then all `DEBIT TRANSACTION` tables for all accounts selected are listed etc.

For each account the page should show up just like this

[image]

Please give me an easy-to-understand answer since I am really a beginner in this sector.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to this with 5 separate datasets, but I think you can do it with just on also.

1. Create on 'main' table on the dataset. use 4 detail rows, 1 column
2. Group it on accountnumber
3. In each detail of the main table, insert a new table with the same dataset.
4. Group those sub-tables also on accountnumber
5. Add a filter to the subtables. set the subtable accountnumber equal to the outer table account number (you can use the expression builder, but it should read something like this: row['ponum'] equals row._outer["ponum"] )

Good luck!